# Cannot preview this file, app may have crashed -- Occurs when inputting specific line of code

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

While I have looked around on stack overflow for answers, it feels like my situation is unique for this error.

I have been learning how to use CoreData in SwiftUI to have persistent data. I started by making a basic movie list, where when you click the "Add Movie" button it adds a movie with some arbitrary text, the point is to get it working.

I have a list in my `ContentView` which does a `ForEach` on the `Movie` entity, however when adding these lines of code:

```
            List {
                ForEach(movies, id: \.self) { (movie: Movie) in
                    Text(movie.title ?? "Unknown Movie")
                }
            }
```

I receive an error:

```
PotentialCrashError: MyMovieList.app may have crashed

MyMovieList.app may have crashed. Check ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports for any crash logs 
from your application.

==================================

|  Error Domain=com.apple.dt.ultraviolet.service Code=12 "Rendering service was interrupted" 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Rendering service was interrupted}
```

But when I build and run the application, it works perfectly. It seems that only the preview breaks when adding that specific line of code. Commenting it out will allow the preview to work again.

My `Movie` entity is only comprised of an attribute `title` which is a String that is optional.

Full code for `ContentView` :

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
// 1
@FetchRequest(
  // 2
  entity: Movie.entity(),
  // 3
  sortDescriptors: [
    NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Movie.title, ascending: true)
  ]
// 4
) var movies: FetchedResults<Movie>

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.addMovie(title: "Generic Movie")
            }) {
                Text("Add Movie")
            }
            List {
                ForEach(movies, id: \.self) { (movie: Movie) in
                    Text(movie.title ?? "Unknown Movie")
                }
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("My Movies")
    }
}
func deleteItem(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    // 1
    offsets.forEach { index in
      // 2
      let movie = self.movies[index]
      // 3
      self.managedObjectContext.delete(movie)
    }
    // 4
    saveContext()
}
func saveContext() {
    do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch {
        print("Error saving managed object context: \(error)")
    }
}
func addMovie(title: String) {
  // 1
  let newMovie = Movie(context: managedObjectContext)

  // 2
  newMovie.title = title

  // 3
  saveContext()
}
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

My `AppDelegate` & `SceneDelegate` are the default that is generated when creating the project, but I will share them here anyways because I know people will ask.

`AppDelegate` :

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {



func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

// MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
    // Called when a new scene session is being created.
    // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
    return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
    // Called when the user discards a scene session.
    // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
    // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
}

// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    /*
     The persistent container for the application. This implementation
     creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
     application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
     error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    */
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyMovieList")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
             
            /*
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
             * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
             * The device is out of space.
             * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
             */
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}

}
```

`SceneDelegate`:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

    // Get the managed object context from the shared persistent container.
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    // Create the SwiftUI view and set the context as the value for the managedObjectContext environment keyPath.
    // Add `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext)` in the views that will need the context.
    let contentView = ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)

    // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}

func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
    // This occurs shortly after the scene enters the background, or when its session is discarded.
    // Release any resources associated with this scene that can be re-created the next time the scene connects.
    // The scene may re-connect later, as its session was not neccessarily discarded (see `application:didDiscardSceneSessions` instead).
}

func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
    // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
}

func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // Called when the scene will move from an active state to an inactive state.
    // This may occur due to temporary interruptions (ex. an incoming phone call).
}

func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
    // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
}

func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // Called as the scene transitions from the foreground to the background.
    // Use this method to save data, release shared resources, and store enough scene-specific state information
    // to restore the scene back to its current state.

    // Save changes in the application's managed object context when the application transitions to the background.
    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.saveContext()
}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set context for the preview in the same way as for application, so here is a solution

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate)
              .persistentContainer.viewContext
        return ContentView()
                  .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your speedy and correct response! Sorry if this was a dumb question, I just finished a SwiftUI course and I'm trying to learn CoreData, so I'm still trying to understand how everything works.